# Issues compiling C++ project using makefile

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I'm having an issue compiling my CS hw using a makefile.  It will compile in CodeBlocks but not with gcc...

->The files are located here... https://github.com/ericmwalsh/cppSortedList

The files are...

SortedList.h

SortedList.cpp (includes SortedList.h)

PCTimer.h

fileListFunctions.cpp (includes PCTimer.h and SortedList.cpp)

testSortedList.cpp (includes fileListFunctions.cpp)

Now I know I'm not supposed to include cpp files within each other but for some reason I am unable to use my makefile:

testmake: SortedList.cpp fileListFunctions.cpp testSortedList.cpp
    
gcc -o testmake SortedList.cpp fileListFunctions.cpp testSortedList.cpp -I.

The error I get is as follows:

```
gcc -o testmake SortedList.cpp fileListFunctions.cpp testSortedList.cpp -I.
In file included from SortedList.cpp:9:
./SortedList.h:41:17: warning: in-class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    int capacity=45500, size=0;
                ^
./SortedList.h:41:29: warning: in-class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    int capacity=45500, size=0;
                            ^
SortedList.cpp:138:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
3 warnings generated.
In file included from fileListFunctions.cpp:10:
./PCTimer.h:32:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cerr'
        cerr << "attempt to start an already running stopwatch" << endl;
        ^
./PCTimer.h:32:68: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
        cerr << "attempt to start an already running stopwatch" << endl;
                                                                   ^
./PCTimer.h:43:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cerr'
        cerr << "attempt to stop a non-running stopwatch" << endl;
        ^
./PCTimer.h:43:62: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
        cerr << "attempt to stop a non-running stopwatch" << endl;
                                                             ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:12:38: error: unknown type name 'SortedArrayList'
void insertAllWords(char * fileName, SortedArrayList * inp){
                                     ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:15:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
    std::ifstream infile(fileName);
    ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:16:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
    for( std::string line; getline( infile, line ); ){
         ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:16:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'infile'
    for( std::string line; getline( infile, line ); ){
                                    ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:18:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
        std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(), ::tolower);
        ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:21:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'infile'
    infile.close();
    ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:23:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'
    cout << "SortedArrayList: Time to insertAllWords from " << fileName << ": " << t.elapsedTime() << " secs" << endl;
    ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:23:114: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
    cout << "SortedArrayList: Time to insertAllWords from " << fileName << ": " << t.elapsedTime() << " secs" << endl;
                                                                                                                 ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:25:36: error: unknown type name 'SortedArrayList'
bool findAllWords(char * fileName, SortedArrayList * inp){
                                   ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:28:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
    std::ifstream infile(fileName);
    ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:29:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
    for( std::string line; getline( infile, line ); ){
         ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:29:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'infile'
    for( std::string line; getline( infile, line ); ){
                                    ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:31:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
        std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(), ::tolower);
        ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:34:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'infile'
    infile.close();
    ^
fileListFunctions.cpp:36:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'
    cout << "SortedArrayList: Time to findAllWords from " << fileName << ": " << t.elapsedTime() << " secs" << endl;
    ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
testSortedList.cpp:12:5: error: unknown type name 'SortedArrayList'
    SortedArrayList * a = new SortedArrayList();
    ^
testSortedList.cpp:12:31: error: unknown type name 'SortedArrayList'
    SortedArrayList * a = new SortedArrayList();
                              ^
testSortedList.cpp:22:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'
    cout << endl << "AFTER REMOVALS:" << endl << endl;
    ^
testSortedList.cpp:22:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
    cout << endl << "AFTER REMOVALS:" << endl << endl;
            ^
testSortedList.cpp:22:42: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
    cout << endl << "AFTER REMOVALS:" << endl << endl;
                                         ^
testSortedList.cpp:22:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
    cout << endl << "AFTER REMOVALS:" << endl << endl;
                                                 ^
testSortedList.cpp:34:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'
    cout << endl << "AFTER INSERTS:" << endl << endl;
    ^
testSortedList.cpp:34:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
    cout << endl << "AFTER INSERTS:" << endl << endl;
            ^
testSortedList.cpp:34:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
    cout << endl << "AFTER INSERTS:" << endl << endl;
                                        ^
testSortedList.cpp:34:49: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
    cout << endl << "AFTER INSERTS:" << endl << endl;
                                                ^
testSortedList.cpp:39:5: error: unknown type name 'SortedLinkedList'
    SortedLinkedList * a = new SortedLinkedList();
    ^
testSortedList.cpp:39:32: error: unknown type name 'SortedLinkedList'
    SortedLinkedList * a = new SortedLinkedList();
                               ^
testSortedList.cpp:49:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'
    cout << endl << endl << "REMOVED AFTER THIS :" << endl << endl;
    ^
testSortedList.cpp:49:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
    cout << endl << endl << "REMOVED AFTER THIS :" << endl << endl;
            ^
testSortedList.cpp:49:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
    cout << endl << endl << "REMOVED AFTER THIS :" << endl << endl;
                    ^
testSortedList.cpp:49:55: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
    cout << endl << endl << "REMOVED AFTER THIS :" << endl << endl;
                                                      ^
testSortedList.cpp:49:63: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
    cout << endl << endl << "REMOVED AFTER THIS :" << endl << endl;
                                                              ^
testSortedList.cpp:57:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'
    cout << "Beginning the testing with SortedArrayList..." << endl << endl;
    ^
testSortedList.cpp:57:64: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endl'
    cout << "Beginning the testing with SortedArrayList..." << endl << endl;
                                                               ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [testmake] Error 1
```

Comment: Why are you including source files into source files? That's not how you use multiple source files. You compile each source file into object files, and then link them together.

Comment: You need to compile in C++11 mode with flag `std=c++11`. Then you need to prefix std lib things with `std::`.

Comment: It also seems that you need a [good book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), as most of the errors listed seems to be beginners mistakes.

Comment: @Joachim - yes I realize this, that is why I am asking this question...  I'm not sure how to properly implement this without borking all my shit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile all the dependent files `(.cpp)` into objects first `(.o)`. And link it with the final object `(main.o)` to form the executable.

Have a look at [How to make a SIMPLE C++ Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481269/how-to-make-simple-c-makefile).

This will work,

```
#Declaration and Definition of Macros which are used in make 
CPP  = g++
OBJ = SortedList.o fileListFunctions.o testSortedList.o
INCS = -I"include" -I"include" -I"." 
BIN=testmake
CXXFLAGS=$(INCS) -O3 -Wall
RM = rm -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(OBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

SortedList.o: SortedList.cpp
    $(CPP) -c SortedList.cpp -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)

fileListFunctions.o: fileListFunctions.cpp
    $(CPP) -c fileListFunctions.cpp -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)

testSortedList.o: testSortedList.cpp
    $(CPP) -c testSortedList.cpp -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Comment: testmake: SortedList.cpp fileListFunctions.cpp testSortedList.cpp
 g++ -o testmake SortedList.cpp fileListFunctions.cpp testSortedList.cpp -I.

Comment: if you git pull the repository i linked, i've just updated the code to what i'm currently working with

^ the above posted make is edited (i changed gcc to g++)

Comment: @EricWalsh You should read about Makefile more in-order to understand it. Anyway posted the makefile which will work for your project. Good luck