# papi_test.h: no file or directory

Tags: performance, papi

I was trying a PAPI code to attach itself to an already running code but on compilation it gives an error
papi_test.h : no such file or directory

```
    #include "papi_test.h"
    #include <sys/ptrace.h>
    #include <limits.h>
  //  #include<papi.h>

    #ifdef _AIX
    #define _LINUX_SOURCE_COMPAT
    #endif

    #if defined(__FreeBSD__)
    # define PTRACE_ATTACH PT_ATTACH
    # define PTRACE_CONT PT_CONTINUE
    #endif

    int
    main( int argc, char *argv[] )
    {
            int retval, num_tests = 1, tmp, i,j=1;
            int EventSet1 = PAPI_NULL;
            long long **values;
            //long long elapsed_us, elapsed_cyc, elapsed_virt_us, elapsed_virt_cyc;
            char event_name[PAPI_MAX_STR_LEN];;
            const PAPI_hw_info_t *hw_info;
            const PAPI_component_info_t *cmpinfo;
            pid_t pid;

            pid = atoi(argv[1]);

            retval = PAPI_library_init( PAPI_VER_CURRENT );
            if ( retval != PAPI_VER_CURRENT )
                    test_fail_exit( __FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_library_init", retval );

            if ( ( cmpinfo = PAPI_get_component_info( 0 ) ) == NULL )
                    test_fail_exit( __FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_get_component_info", 0 );

            if ( cmpinfo->attach == 0 )
                    test_skip( __FILE__, __LINE__, "Platform does not support attaching",
                                       0 );

            hw_info = PAPI_get_hardware_info(  );
            if ( hw_info == NULL )
                    test_fail_exit( __FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_get_hardware_info", 0 );

            /* add PAPI_TOT_CYC and one of the events in PAPI_FP_INS, PAPI_FP_OPS or
               PAPI_TOT_INS, depending on the availability of the event on the
               platform */
            retval = PAPI_create_eventset(&EventSet1);
            if ( retval != PAPI_OK )
                    test_fail_exit( __FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_create_eventset", retval );

            /* Here we are testing that this does not cause a fail */

            retval = PAPI_assign_eventset_component( EventSet1, 0 );
            if ( retval != PAPI_OK )
                    test_fail( __FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_assign_eventset_component",
                    retval );

            retval = PAPI_attach( EventSet1, ( unsigned long ) pid );
            if ( retval != PAPI_OK )
                    test_fail_exit( __FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_attach", retval );

            sprintf(event_name,"PAPI_LD_INS");

            retval = PAPI_add_event(EventSet1, PAPI_LD_INS);
            if ( retval != PAPI_OK )
                    test_fail_exit( __FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_add_event", retval );

            retval = PAPI_add_event(EventSet1, PAPI_SR_INS);
            if ( retval != PAPI_OK )
                    test_fail_exit( __FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_add_event", retval );

            retval = PAPI_add_event(EventSet1, PAPI_BR_INS);
            if ( retval != PAPI_OK )

                    if ( retval != PAPI_OK )
                    test_fail_exit( __FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_add_event", retval );

            values = allocate_test_space( 1, 3);

            printf("After %d\n",retval);

            retval = PAPI_start( EventSet1 );
            if ( retval != PAPI_OK )
                    test_fail_exit( __FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_start", retval );

            printf("Continuing\n");

            //for( i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++) { j += i;}
            sleep ( 10 );
            retval = PAPI_stop( EventSet1, values[0] );
            if ( retval != PAPI_OK )
              test_fail_exit( __FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_stop", retval );

            retval = PAPI_cleanup_eventset(EventSet1);
            if (retval != PAPI_OK)
              test_fail_exit( __FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_cleanup_eventset", retval );

            retval = PAPI_destroy_eventset(&EventSet1);
            if (retval != PAPI_OK)
              test_fail_exit( __FILE__, __LINE__, "PAPI_destroy_eventset", retval );

            printf( "Test case: 3rd party attach start, stop.\n" );

            printf
                    ( "-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" );

            printf( "Test type    : \t           1\n" );
            printf( TAB1, "PAPI_LD_INS : \t", ( values[0] )[0] );
            printf( TAB1, "PAPI_SR_INS : \t", ( values[0] )[1] );
            printf( TAB1, "PAPI_BR_INS : \t", ( values[0] )[2] );
            printf
                    ( "-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" );

            printf( "Verification: none\n" );

            test_pass( __FILE__, values, num_tests );
            exit( 1 );
    }
```

Even when compiling the file attach_target.c in the papi-5.3.0/src/ctests folder same error comes.
I want to monitor an already running C code using PAPI and attch the counters to it.

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: using gcc <filename> -lpapi

Comment: Looks like you are missing the include files path, try `gcc -I/path/to/papi.h/dir -c <filename> -L/path/to/papi/library -lpapi`

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine after giving the path. There is one more thing i wanted to ask, can PAPI used to monitor a third process say a C program andmonitor the events?? i.e. attaching to that C program ( which may spawn new threads or uses fork) ??

Comment: I don't think papi allows you to do that, but I'm not sure. It would be better to ask another question with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the include PATH (and probably the library path too), compile with:

```
gcc -I/path/to/papi/include/dir -c <filename> -L/path/to/papi/libs -lpapi
```

Additionally, you might benefit from a Makefile. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2481326/1392758) is very fine explanation in "How to write a simple Makefile" and presumably everything you need to start with `make`

Comment: can u write the link again ... may be the hyperlink is not visible