# What is the format of a makefile for c++

Tags: c++, makefile

I previously used commands like

```
g++ myfile.cpp -o myoutput
```

to compile my c++ code, but I wanna shift to make use of makefiles. So I don't know weather I sound Dumb or not, What is the simple format of a makefile

Like I have a cpp file named `template.cpp`, how do I compile it using `make`?

Comment: We ate not Google Now ...

Comment: When I'm googling it shows some much more complex examples, which in this case I don't need.

Comment: If that's all you need, then you don't need a makefile. Just type `make myfile` and it will compile and link `myfile.cpp`. Lots more info here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: dump makefiles and go for meta-build systems like cmake, premake, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest makefile, for what you asked, looks like this:

```
myfile: myfile.cpp
    g++ myfile.cpp -o myfile
```

Note that that's a hard tab on the second line. If you have this in a file called `makefile` then you can run `make` from the terminal to compile your code.

By the way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2481326/4750117) is an excellent tutorial to writing makefiles -- well worth the read.

Answer (score -2):

I recommed you this link. It introduce you to easy learning how to do makefiles for cpp [makefiles easy](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/writing-makefiles/)

I also recommend you this template, that I use fron here [template](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)

```
# A sample Makefile
# This Makefile demonstrates and explains 
# Make Macros, Macro Expansions,
# Rules, Targets, Dependencies, Commands, Goals
# Artificial Targets, Pattern Rule, Dependency Rule.

# Comments start with a # and go to the end of the line.

# Here is a simple Make Macro.
LINK_TARGET = test_me.exe

# Here is a Make Macro that uses the backslash to extend to multiple lines.
OBJS =  \
 Test1.o \
 Test2.o \
 Main.o

# Here is a Make Macro defined by two Macro Expansions.
# A Macro Expansion may be treated as a textual replacement of the Make Macro.
# Macro Expansions are introduced with $ and enclosed in (parentheses).
REBUILDABLES = $(OBJS) $(LINK_TARGET)

# Here is a simple Rule (used for "cleaning" your build environment).
# It has a Target named "clean" (left of the colon ":" on the first line),
# no Dependencies (right of the colon),
# and two Commands (indented by tabs on the lines that follow).
# The space before the colon is not required but added here for clarity.
clean : 
  rm -f $(REBUILDABLES)
  echo Clean done

# There are two standard Targets your Makefile should probably have:
# "all" and "clean", because they are often command-line Goals.
# Also, these are both typically Artificial Targets, because they don't typically
# correspond to real files named "all" or "clean".  

# The rule for "all" is used to incrementally build your system.
# It does this by expressing a dependency on the results of that system,
# which in turn have their own rules and dependencies.
all : $(LINK_TARGET)
  echo All done

# There is no required order to the list of rules as they appear in the Makefile.
# Make will build its own dependency tree and only execute each rule only once
# its dependencies' rules have been executed successfully.

# Here is a Rule that uses some built-in Make Macros in its command:
# $@ expands to the rule's target, in this case "test_me.exe".
# $^ expands to the rule's dependencies, in this case the three files
# main.o, test1.o, and  test2.o.
$(LINK_TARGET) : $(OBJS)
  g++ -g -o $@ $^

# Here is a Pattern Rule, often used for compile-line.
# It says how to create a file with a .o suffix, given a file with a .cpp suffix.
# The rule's command uses some built-in Make Macros:
# $@ for the pattern-matched target
# $< for the pattern-matched dependency
%.o : %.cpp
  g++ -g -o $@ -c $<

# These are Dependency Rules, which are rules without any command.
# Dependency Rules indicate that if any file to the right of the colon changes,
# the target to the left of the colon should be considered out-of-date.
# The commands for making an out-of-date target up-to-date may be found elsewhere
# (in this case, by the Pattern Rule above).
# Dependency Rules are often used to capture header file dependencies.
Main.o : Main.h Test1.h Test2.h
Test1.o : Test1.h Test2.h
Test2.o : Test2.h

# Alternatively to manually capturing dependencies, several automated
# dependency generators exist.  Here is one possibility (commented out)...
# %.dep : %.cpp
#   g++ -M $(FLAGS) $< > $@
# include $(OBJS:.o=.dep)
```

Comment: I support Your answer but It would be Nice if You Showed Me a Working Example of it in your answer!

Comment: [Link only answers are discouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer)