# Sublime Text 3 c++ undefined reference to classes

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I'm able to compile single file code but not anything with separate file classes. This works in code blocks, but not sublime text. I couldn't find any information on this topic so I'm asking here.

Here is my code (all in one folder):

#### main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Cat c;

  cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

#### Cat.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"

using namespace std;

Cat::Cat()
{
  cout << "i am cat bboiii";
}
```

#### Cat.h:

```
#ifndef CAT_H
#define CAT_H


class Cat
{
    public:
        Cat();
};

#endif // CAT_H
```

Comment: Do you have a make file? How are you telling sublime (which by default just runs `make`) which files to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is most definitely with your `Makefile`. Whenever you split your code into header and source files you need to tell your compiler where to find those header files.

```
g++ -I/path/to/header Cat.cpp main.cpp -o Cat
```

The `-I` flag tells the compiler to `include` header files from the path you give it. If all your files are in one folder (which in your case they are), you can simply compile them as

```
g++ -I. Cat.cpp main.cpp -o Cat
```

where `.` stands for the current directory or

```
g++ Cat.cpp main.cpp -o Cat
```

as the compiler looks for headers in the current directory by default. As your project size grows, you will need to prepare your `Makefile` to automate the build process. The simplest Makefile would be

```
all:
   g++ Cat.cpp main.cpp -o Cat
```

and then you simply run `make` in the directory containing your makefile. I suggest you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2481326/2750396) on how to make practical makefiles.

Comment: `-I.` does nothing. The compiler looks for header files in the current directory by default.

Comment: True. I just added that for the sake of comprehension. Would edit to mention this as well.