# How can I compile my CPP project on debian?

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, debian

I just moved my project from my PC into a virtual machine running Debian.
My project contains some classes and headers, how can I compile it with G++?

```
ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2369 Nov 27 20:17 Card.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1299 Nov 27 15:56 Deck.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6529 Nov 27 20:58 Game.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4639 Nov 27 20:12 Hand.cpp
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 27 20:00 inc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   19 Nov 18 10:35 main.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5113 Nov 27 20:05 Player.cpp
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 28 07:58 src

/src ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 490 Nov 28 07:58 reviiyot.cpp (this is the main)

/inc ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1506 Nov 26 17:31 Card.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  842 Nov 25 12:25 Deck.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  830 Nov 26 23:55 Game.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  774 Nov 27 15:55 Hand.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2383 Nov 27 20:00 Player.h
```

Comment: Don't post pictures. `ls -l` and copy-paste the file list.

Comment: You can use `make` file for compilation.

Comment: @MSalters Got it, edited the post.

Comment: im using: `make -f reviiyot.cpp` and i get the error: `reviiyot.cpp:5: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: @EladCohen You don't have a Makefile? At least I can't spot one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify both all your .cpp files as well as the path to the include directory, so in your case the compile command could look something like

`g++ src/reviiyot.cpp -I inc/ ./*.cpp -o executableFile`

Note: it would be more natural to place the implementation files of your headers (the .cpp files, except your main) inside the `src/` directory and leave the `main.cpp` inside the main directory

Answer (score 1):

You have to link all the required sources together:

eg.:

```
g++ src/reviiyot.cpp main.cpp Hand.cpp Game.cpp Deck.cpp Card.cpp  Player.cpp -Wall -o MyProgram
```

Alternatively, you can [create a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481269/how-to-make-a-simple-c-makefile/2481326#2481326).

Comment: Do i have to link the headers [inside inc] as well?

Comment: No: if they are included in the programs via #include <headerpath.h>.