# How to make a single "makefile" create 3 output binaries

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

could anyone help me create a makefile for my project? I need 3 binaries to be created from the makefile.

The binaries compile individually like this:

`gcc -D_POSIX_SOURCE -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread main.c service_client_socket.c service_listen_socket.c get_listen_socket.c -o serverThreaded`

`gcc -D_POSIX_SOURCE -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread main.c service_client_socket.c service_listen_socket.c get_listen_socket.c -o server`

(So it creates 2 identical binaries but with different names, serverThreaded and server)

and also I need this from the makefile too:

`gcc -D_POSIX_SOURCE -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread client.c -o client`

Edit: I think this is what I need?

```
all: serverThreaded server client

    gcc -D_POSIX_SOURCE -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread main.c service_client_socket.c service_listen_socket.c get_listen_socket.c -o serverThreaded 
    gcc -D_POSIX_SOURCE -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread main.c service_client_socket.c service_listen_socket.c get_listen_socket.c -o server 
    gcc -D_POSIX_SOURCE -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread client.c -o client 
    .PHONY: all
```

Comment: This question made the impression that you already have a `makefile` that creates one file, and now you want to change it so it creates 3 files. Now (after the edit) it seems that you don't have any `makefile` at all! You might want to consider not using `makefile`, and using just a shell-script to do your compilation. Or look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2481307/509868) for an example of a simple `makefile`.

Comment: @anatolyg My assignment is going to be automatically compiled from the makefile, so it's unfortunately a requirement for me to make one. I worked out how to use it to compile one file but that's all I can get to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a *phony* rule (that is a rule that doesn't build a file itself) which has whatever you want to build as its prerequisites. By convention, this rule is called `all` in most Makefiles. For your case, it would look like this:

```
all: serverThreaded server client
```

It's also common to put this as the **very first rule**, so if you just type `make` without a target, it is automatically selected.

An important thing to do is to let `make` know this rule actually **is** "phony" by putting it in the prerequisites of the special target `.PHONY` like this:

```
.PHONY: all
```

This is necessary because otherwise, `make` would expect it to build a file called `all`. If you'd ever have a file `all` in your current directory which is newer than all files you actually build, `make` wouldn't do anything.

---

Regarding the edit, it doesn't make any sense. Explaining `make` entirely isn't possible in this Q&A format, so I'll just give you an example how a very basic `Makefile` could look like, as a start:

```
CC:= gcc
CFLAGS:= -D_POSIX_SOURCE -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread
LIBS:= -pthread

serverThreaded_OBJS:= main.o service_client_socket.o service_listen_socket.o get_listen_socket.o
server_OBJS:= main.o service_client_socket.o service_listen_socket.o get_listen_socket.o
client_OBJS:= client.o

all: serverThreaded server client

serverThreaded: $(serverThreaded_OBJS)
    $(CC) -o$@ $^ $(LIBS)

server: $(server_OBJS)
    $(CC) -o$@ $^ $(LIBS)

client: $(client_OBJS)
    $(CC) -o$@ $^ $(LIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o$@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o

.PHONY: all clean
```

As a side note, it's strange how your `serverThreaded` and `server` are built from the exact same sources with the exact same flags -- you will end up with the exact same binaries.

Comment: My knowledge of make files is poor. Would my complete makefile look like this then?

`all: serverThreaded server client
<tab>gcc -D_POSIX_SOURCE -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread main.c service_client_socket.c service_listen_socket.c get_listen_socket.c -o serverThreaded`


`<tab>gcc -D_POSIX_SOURCE -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread main.c service_client_socket.c service_listen_socket.c get_listen_socket.c -o server`


`<tab>gcc -D_POSIX_SOURCE -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread client.c -o client`


`.PHONY: all`

Comment: @toastedDeli But I guess it's completely wrong. Your `all` rule typically shouldn't have a recipe. Instead, have three other rules `serverThreaded`, `server` and `client` which have a recipe that builds the respective binary. You should go one step further and have a pattern rule `%.o: %.c` building the individual object files to take full advantage of `make` ... please read some manuals/books etc first.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the assignment has 2 parts; creating a single threaded server and creating a multithreaded server. I just implemented the multi t hreaded one only to save time.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an artificial target as the first one.  By convention, this target is usually called `all`.  Then you can list all the dependencies you actually want to build:

```
all: serverThreaded server client
```

See [this discussion of the default goal](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html).

Comment: Never forget to list this as `.PHONY` though!