# Unable to initialize vector with initializer list in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vector, initialization

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};
    for (int x : v)
    {
        cout << x << ' ';
    }
return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code in vscode I receive the following ERROR:

> non-aggregate type 'vector' cannot be initialized with an initializer list gcc [7, 17]

**NOTICE** - the error includes gcc even though that is not the compiler I am using.

The code compiles fine in the terminal and in Xcode so I know it has something to do with vscode. How do I fix this issue?

**NOTE** - I am using I C/C++ IntelliSense with the following configurations: Compiler Path (/usr/bin/clang++) IntelliSense mode (macros-clang-arm64) Include path (${workspaceFolder}/**) C standard (c17) C++ standard (C++17).

Comment: Did you enable c++11 or later?

Comment: How would I check whether I am using C++11 or later in VSCode? I have been search the web for a clear and concise answer but to no avail.

Comment: it might be result of default settings being baked into your project already, Are you using platformio? You might need upgrade it or  fix its config file.

Comment: Your code works fine in the latest gcc: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nqcvsecd6

Comment: I know the code works fine on online compilers. It also works just fine in my terminal. This issue is somewhere between MacOS and VSCode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied your code and named it `test.cpp`. I faced the same issue and I solved it by adding some configurations. Find `tasks.json` and add something in `args`.

```
"args": [
    "-g",
    "-Wall",
    "-std=c++11",
    "test.cpp"
]
```

It works on my MAC! I used `command+shift+B` to compile and it generated `a.out` after compiling. Then you can run it by `F5`. I also post my `launch.json` here, where `/Users/work/Foo` is my workspaceFolder. Pay attention to the line of `program`, I have changed this line. Good luck!

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "/Users/work/Foo",
      "environment": [],
      "program": "/Users/work/Foo/a.out",
      "MIMode": "lldb",
      "externalConsole": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might post your code and how you're compiling it. The following worked for me:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and run like so:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
$ ./a.out
1 2 3 4
$
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your code and saved it to a test.cpp file, then ran the same two commands in the terminal:
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
$ ./a.out

Then received the same output:
1 2 3 4

However, when I run test.cpp in vscode I receive the following error:
"non-aggregate type 'std::vector<int>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list"

Why is this?

My configs are as followed:
Compiler Path = /usr/bin/g++
IntelliSense Mode = macos-gcc-x64
C++ standard = c++17

Comment: I honestly don't know much about vscode or how to configure it to compile C++ code. Maybe this answer would help with setting flags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57173879/19410 

I wish I could help. You might edit your question with these details and I'll vote to reopen. Or ask a new question?

Comment: I edited the question. A vote to reopen the question would help greatly. I cannot ask another question due to I asking the question incorrectly the first two times.

Comment: why write the for loop full if we have ranged for loops, and why not use `auto` for the iterator type. why not use `cbegin()` and `cend()`

Comment: @rioV8 If this is relevant to what is failing in Vscode, definitely add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

On my mac, I have tried to change the CppStandard to no avail.

Instead what worked for me:

g++ -std=c++11 filename.cpp

./a.out

Comment: Hello Nisky, I wanted to clarify that the question is specifically about how to specify the C++ standard in VSCode, rather than in the terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Have you gone through this official tutorial thoroughly?
[Configure VS Code for clang on macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Most probably you have have not configured your `tasks.json` correctly. Your build system is not using the right c++ standard.
Can you post your `tasks.json` so that we can understand your configuration exactly.

Here is the `tasks.json` file config from documentation:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "clang++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
      "args": [
        "-std=c++17",
        "-stdlib=libc++",
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: I don't have reputation to comment on question, so asking you here.