# Problem with running openMP code in Visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, openmp

I am trying to run the following code in VS code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "omp.h"

int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int ID  = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("hello(%d)",ID);
        printf("world(%d\n",ID);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\nokni\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\C C++\" && gcc test.c -o test && "c:\Users\nokni\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\C C++\"test
C:\Users\nokni\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKN9XFE.o:test.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `-fopenmp` compiler flag

Comment: I am not super familiar with compiler flags. Could you please specify where exactly I should have added this flag? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173093/how-to-include-compiler-flags-in-visual-studio-code