# How to compile multiple c++ files on Mac Terminal with warnings?

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, g++

I am used to compiling a single main.cpp file with warnings using this command on terminal:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra std=c++14 main.cpp -o main
```

Let's say I have 2 more files (file_1.cpp, file_2.cpp) that will link with main.cpp.
I saw this command that compiles such files:

```
g++ -I path -c file_1.cpp -o file_1.o
g++ -I path -c file_2.cpp -o file_2.o
```

where `path` is the path directory of the header files. And then I compile the main.cpp and link it to the previous objects with:

```
g++ -I path -o main main.cpp file_1.o file_2.o
```

If I want to include the warnings `-Wall -Wextra` and standard `-std=c++14`, where do I write such options? On the final compilation of main.cpp, in each compilation of every file, somewhere else, or don't need to at all?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to compile from command line, instead of an IDE or makefile like system?

Comment: @RichardCritten no reason, I am kind of new to programming and I was taught to use the command line instead of an IDE, so I am a bit used to this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the flags in every compilation so you will get the warnings earlier. But I would prefer to create a makefile to automate the build process instead of typing everything. The following issue has good information about it -> [How to make a SIMPLE C++ Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481269/how-to-make-a-simple-c-makefile)